# Retrieve the number of opened QMainWindows in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I am calling several times to open QMainWindow. How can I get the number of windows which are opened in my Application?

```
void mywindow :: keyPressEvent (QKeyEvent *event)
{ 

    switch(event->key())
    {
       case Qt::Key_Enter:
           popUpWindow();
    }
}

void mywindow :: popUpWindow()
{

    win = new QMainWindow();
    win->show();
}
```

I am closing these windows in `deleteWindow()`. But I want to know the number of windows which are already opened.

Comment: Can't you, like, update a counter variable yourself? It's pretty trivial, really.

Comment: Thanks bro. Ya i can use counter variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [static method](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#topLevelWidgets) `QWidgetList QApplication::topLevelWidgets () [static]` to get all opened windows.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `mywindow` class you add:

```
unsigned count;
```

as a member object initialized to `0` (or `1` depending on how many windows you show at the beginning). Then in the `popUpWindow` member function you do `count++;` and in your `deleteWindow` member function you do `count--;`.

Here's the skeleton of your class:

```
class mywindow {
private:
    unsigned windowCount;
public:
    mywindow() : windowCount(0) {}

    void popUpWindow() {
        // ...
        windowCount++;
    }

    void deleteWindow() {
        // ...
        windowCount--;
    }
};
```